# אוּלַי means we want it to happen

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-toldot

The Posuk says:

> [אוּלַי יְמֻשֵּׁנִי אָבִי](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%9B%D7%96_%D7%99%D7%91)

Translated as: *maybe* my father will tap me (and realize, and curse me)

The question is accoring to the [GRA](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41943&pgnum=81) the word אוּלַי indicates that you want the thing to happen so why did Yackov want to get caught?

Answer (score 3):

Presumably Yaakov is so uncomfortable with these falsehoods that it's a Freudian slip -- he almost wants to get caught.

Comment: I wouldn't even call it a slip. He's doing his best to dissuade Rivkah from sending him, after all.

Comment: I heard in a shiur last week that in "Maayan Bais Hasho'eivah" Rav Schwab refers to Yaakov's "mirmoh" as part of his his kibud ov v'aim. Worth looking up; I can't find an online edition.

Comment: "Presumably" is a strong word.